# How to download & save files from the assets folder of React Native Expo app to a physical device?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Actually, I add some images to the assets folder of my React Native Expo app. I want that when a user opens my app, they can download or save these images on their physical device. I have tried many times, but I haven't found a solution. I tried the below code which works fine on the Expo Go app, but when I install the APK and open the app, it doesn't download the images. Can you please suggest a solution for this?

I have tried this, it's working on the expo go app but not on physical devices.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, Image} from 'react-native'
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import {Asset} from 'expo-asset';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Test = () => {

  //Example Image Url = require('../assets/nk/myimage.jpg')
  const route = useRoute(); 
  const saveFileToMediaLibrary = async () => {
    try {
      const asset = Asset.fromModule(route.params.u);
      // Download the asset to the local file system
      await asset.downloadAsync();
      // Get the local URI of the downloaded file
      const fileUri = asset.localUri;
    // File saved successfully
      console.log('File saved to media library:', fileUri);
      
      // Save the file to the media library
      const perm = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (perm.status != "granted") {
          return;
        }

        try {
          const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
          console.log(asset);
          const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync("My App Images");
          if (album == null) {
            await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("My App Images", asset, false);
          } else {
            await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          alert("Something Went Wrong..."+ e);
        }
    } catch (error) {
      alert('Error to save file in media library', fileUri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Download File" onPress={()=>{saveFileToMediaLibrary()}} />
      <Image 
      source={route.params.u} style={{width:100,height:100}}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

Comment: Dont speak of downloading. The files are already on the device. They only have to be copied to file system.

Comment: @blackapps how we can copy these images from the fileSystem to the device's storage?

Comment: No, from the resource to file system.

Comment: Copying from assets to file system is a pretty standard operation. You open an inputstream for the resource and a file outputstream for the file. Then you make a loop where you read chunks from input and write them to output. Just like a normal file copy.

Comment: I don't understand, can you provide me with any example regarding this issue?

Comment: No, i do not program in react-. But as it is a standard operation a little googling should bring you the code.

Answer (score 0):

I use below code to copy sqlite database from asset folder along with project, maybe you can try with the images

```
  if (
    !(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite"))
      .exists
  ) {
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite"
    );
  }

    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      Asset.fromModule(require("../SQLite/data.db")).uri,
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + "SQLite/data.db"
    );
```

Reference: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/